# Passing a nested dictionary to requests module

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a nested dictionary, which I want to pass to a web service (written in PHP) and am struggling, as I can't access the data I need.

The dictionary looks something like

```
import requests
from nested_dict import nested_dict

data = nested_dict()

data['name'] = 'test'

data['cookies']['PHPSESSID']['name'] = 'PHPSESSID'
data['cookies']['PHPSESSID']['essential'] = 'Essential'

data['cookies']['CookieNotice']['name'] = 'CookieNotice'
data['cookies']['CookieNotice']['essential'] = 'Essential'
```

Then I make my request:

```
r = requests.post('someurl.com', data = data)
```

In the receiving url someurl.com (written in PHP), I can access the first level no problem eg

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = $_REQUEST;
$response['content'] = $data['name'];
$response = $response['content'];
echo json_encode($response);
```

The problem is trying to access the data in the nested dict. I don't know what form this is arriving in when it hits someurl.com, and as a result I can't use to produce a loop. What I want to do is this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = $_REQUEST;
$response['content'] = $data['name'];
  foreach ($data['cookies'] as $k => $v):
  $response['content'] .= $k." ".$v;
endforeach;

$response = $response['content'];
echo json_encode($response);
```

When the response is printed out in the template, there is content present for the nested section ...

Any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I have tried many permutations but still struggling! I just need to be able to pass a nested dict (or json) to my receiving url 'someurl.com' and be able to (json) decode that in PHP eg $d = json_decode($_POST)

this 'works' but I can't 'do' anything with the response:

```
dat = json.dumps(data)
req = requests.get('someurl.com',params=dat)
```

I can't do anything when trying to use requests.post, and if I pass the original dictionary or convert it to json.

Many thanks

Comment: Try using `json` instead of `data`, i.e. `requests.post('someurl.com', json=data)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. I get a JSONDecodeError when I try that. Do you how I can inspect what is being passed to someurl.com? (In PHP) I have tried $data = json_decode($_REQUEST), and tried $response['content'] = $data['source']; echo json_encode($response); but get an error

Comment: how about `requests.post('someurl.com', json=data.to_dict())`?

Comment: Hi, sorry still nothing. With pretty much all of the permutations I've tried my exception gets thrown. try:req = requests.post('someurl.com'',json=data.to_dict(), timeout=3.00). In my receiving url, the response is just returning $_REQUEST or $_POST, and I get the same result - the exception being thrown. Very frustating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution which worked for me was as follows:

```
import requests,json
from nested_dict import nested_dict

data = nested_dict()

data['name'] = 'test'

data['cookies']['PHPSESSID']['name'] = 'PHPSESSID'
data['cookies']['PHPSESSID']['essential'] = 'Essential'

data['cookies']['CookieNotice']['name'] = 'CookieNotice'
data['cookies']['CookieNotice']['essential'] = 'Essential'

datajson = json.dumps(data)

req = requests.post('someurl.com/myendpoint.php',data={'payload':datajson},timeout=3.00)
```

and then in the PHP script at someurl.com/myendpoint.php I could then work with the $_POST

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['payload']);
```

Answer (score 3):

For Python requests module, this is bad:

```
requests.post(url, data=nested_dict)
```

Good:

```
requests.post(url, json=nested_dict)
```

Note: `nested_dict` does not need to be stringified. Just pass it in as dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I personally need to use `data=` since I'm trying to use form data